# Variable constrain in FiPy

Tags: python, fipy

I have an equation, solved using FiPy, where my results are stored in a matrix result
--> result[t][-1] indicates the outlet value (1D mesh) in time t

I would like to use this outlet value as an inlet value (constrain) in another equation. Note that this value will vary in time. Is that possible to do so in FiPy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with FiPy's lazy evaluation, but you can call `.setValue()` on the variable defining the constraint at each time step.